# python - how to run the files on another computer without VS2015

Tags: python, visual-c++

I have a pc with vs2015 installed - python and vc++ compiler added to it. I am able to run my codes Main.py etc with PySNMP and PyMySql on this pc. **I just want to compile these files on this pc, and run it on another server** (which is not having VS2015 installed on it). Is it possible to do this (distribution) similar to a jar files in Java. That server doesnot have internet.
Please guide.

Comment: Python is not a compiled programming language and does not require Visual Studio (it requires a Python interpreter, such as CPython). And you can just bundle/copy any compiled libraries (as long as the executing machine uses the same hardware architecture and operating system)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Ya, it is known that VS2015 is not required for  Python to run, but the pblm was I was not sure how to accomplish this without VS2015. While I run the .py on that machince, it asked for several dependencies libs and while I started installing them one by one, one error was "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat", which I fixed on existing  PC by installing VC++ on VS2015. I didnot knew how to fix it without VS2015.  However, finally installed VC++ distribution etc or somehow, it started to work on the Server now......Will try on another server and update the steps.

Comment: **vcvarsall.bat** is a batch file that comes with Visual Studio, it is used to set up environment variables for using the Visual C++ compiler through the command line. I guess you were trying to install some Python libraries which contained native code and needed to be compiled. However once you have the compiled libraries you should be able to just copy them to the target machine (it may still require some Visual C++ runtime libraries, but not the entirety of Visual Studio and the compiler).

Comment: thanks, thats exactly I was looking for.